# GraphQL query isn't refreshed with graphene-django

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

Here's my schema definition:

```
class TemperatureRecordType(DjangoObjectType):
  unit = graphene.String()
  class Meta:
    model = TemperatureRecord
    fields = ("timestamp", "value")

  def resolve_unit(parent, info):
    return "Celcius"

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  currentTemperature = DjangoListField(TemperatureRecordType)

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Query is :

```
{
  currentTemperature{
    timestamp
    value
    unit
  }
}
```

There's only one entry in TemperatureRecord, with `value` and `timestamp` changed by a management command every second running the `refresh` method in my model's class :

```
class TemperatureRecord(models.Model):
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now) # Last time temperature value changed
  value = models.IntegerField(default=get_random_temperature_value) # Value to be changed every second, always in Celcius

  def refresh(self): # Updates entry's temperature value and timestamp
    self.value = get_random_temperature_value()
    self.timestamp = now()
    self.save()
```

Here's the management command :

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Refreshes temperature record every second, indefinitely'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
      while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
          TemperatureRecord.objects.get().refresh()
        except TemperatureRecord.DoesNotExist:
          TemperatureRecord.objects.create()
```

Django shell works fine and shows data changes every second, but Graphene always returns the same stale data, and only refreshes if I change my schema and save the file.

Is there some sort of caching? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many records the `TemperatureRecord` have?

Comment: Just one record here